# How do you minimise sum of atmosphere and gravity loss?

Tags: space-shuttle, trajectory

I am attempting to calculate the optimum trajectory of a space shuttle going into orbit, taking into account gravitational and atmospheric losses. How would it be possible to minimise the sum of these losses and thus plot an optimum trajectory?

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/744/effect-of-atmospheric-drag-on-rocket-launches-and-benefits-of-high-altitude-laun

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5419/climbing-at-terminal-velocity-minimizes-losses-but-why-and-of-what

Comment: It depends on the drag of the specific vehicle.  The higher the weight-to-drag of the vehicle the more you want to turn.

Comment: Duplicate question, with answers, on [Physics Stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) : [How can you work out the most efficient path of a space shuttle going into space, taking into account gravity and atmosphere loss?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/384273).

Comment: Those answers are awful.